# Trying to cut inside ellipse path

Tags: inkscape

[image]

Just starting to learn inkscape. Trying to erase the part of my pattern that's inside the circle, leaving the circle and the outside part. The circle and pattern are two separate objects. Just can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Bring the circle shape to the top of the stack using `Object` > `Raise to Top`, and apply a white fill to the circle.

[image: Example showing white fill]

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the circle.

Path menu: difference with one of the circles and the waved outline. For this, the circle has to be above the waved outline.
Then the inner part might be empty.